Error: Problem: conflicting requests - nothing provides perl(lib) needed by git-2.45.0-1.fc40.x86_64 from iut-updates
I'm using fedora 40 with domestic mirror names iut.repo. when I want to install git by
sudo dnf install git
I got this error:`
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:12 ago on Fri 17 May 2024 02:57:10 PM +0330.
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides perl(lib) needed by git-2.45.0-1.fc40.x86_64 from iut-updates
  - nothing provides perl(File::Find) needed by git-2.45.0-1.fc40.x86_64 from iut-updates
  - nothing provides perl(Term::ReadKey) needed by git-2.45.0-1.fc40.x86_64 from iut-updates`

any idea what should I do?
I tried use another DNS, comeback to last mirrors and change my IP but all I got is just this different error:
`
Repository updates-source is listed more than once in the configuration
Last metadata expiration check: 0:15:20 ago on Fri 17 May 2024 02:57:10 PM +0330.
No match for argument: git
Error: Unable to find a match: git`

